# Embed wordpress admin in an iframe

Tags: html, security, wordpress, iframe, blogs

I am trying to embed the admin "new post" wordpress page into an iframe:

```
<iframe height="500px" frameborder="0" width="740px" src="my_wordpress_domain/wp-admin/post-new.php"/>
```

For some reason the iframe loads a blank page. The link itself works in a separate tab and so does the wordpress home page within an iframe.

Is this a security issue, if so, how can I circumvent it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in fact this is a vulnerability.  Wordpress recently patched a [remote code execution click-jacking vulnerability](http://www.morningstarsecurity.com/research/clickjacking-wordpress).  In order to patch a clickjacking vulnerability you revoke iframe access.

In order to get the iframe to work you'll have to modify the `x-frame-options` HTTP header that is being set by wordpress.  You can change this header to "same-origin" which allows iframe's from the same domain.  Or you could whitelist your domain on this list.

**DO NOT REMOVE THE `x-frame-options` HEADER.**